# Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why am I getting a NullPointerException with this code?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

    int i = 0;
    Job[] job = new Job[100];
    File f = new File("Jobs.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        job[i].start = input.nextInt();
        job[i].end = input.nextInt();
        job[i].weight = input.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
}
```

I get the error at the very first line of the while loop on its very first run-through. I also have a separate class:

```
public class Job {
    public int start, end, weight;
}
```

and the text file:

```
0 3 3
1 4 2
0 5 4
3 6 1
4 7 2
3 9 5
5 10 2
8 10 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks all! Simple mistake, simple answer.

Comment: Happens to every programmer, Someday :)

Comment: NPE problem without a stacktrace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

- Calling the instance method of a null object.
- Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
- Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
- Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
- Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

  Job[] job = new Job[100];

As of now all values in array are `null`. Because you not inserted any Job objects inside.

```
  job[i].start = input.nextInt(); // job[i]  is null.
```

What you have to do is just initialize a new `Job` object and  assign to the current `index`.

Becomes,

```
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        Job job = new Job(); 
        job.start = input.nextInt();
        job.end = input.nextInt();
        job.weight = input.nextInt();
        job[i] =job;
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

See [4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For all reference types [(§4.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3), the default value is **null**.

You need to initialize `job` array before trying to access it, now it's like writing `null.start`, which of course causes [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Was looking for that for about 3 mins :D

Answer (score 4):

You just initialized an array of `Job` type, you haven't initialized each element in the array, hence the exception.

```
 while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        job[i] = new Job(); // initialize here
        job[i].start = input.nextInt();
        job[i].end = input.nextInt();
        job[i].weight = input.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
```